# GWT Super dev mode 2.6.0

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am new to GWT and dont know how to fix this.

Connection received from 127.0.0.1:57841
[ERROR] Unrecognized command for client; closing connection
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelException: Invalid message type 71
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$Message.readMessageType(BrowserChannel.java:1072)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:391)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't super dev mode - "BrowserChannel" is part of legacy dev mode. Make sure you are passing `-superDevMode` to DevMode when you start it.